# How to store json arrays api in sqlite db

Tags: android, sqlite

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Single Bed Sheet"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Double Bed Sheet"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Single Bed Cover"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Double Bed Cover"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Pillow Cover"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Bath Towel"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "Hand Towel"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "Bath Mat"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "Yellow Bed Sheet"
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "Color Towel"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are showing an array of 'objects'.  Those objects have properties such as 'id' and 'name'.  What you would normally do, is create a class object with those properties.  Then, when you retrieve the JSON Array, you would iterate through that array and create a new instance of your class object and populate it from the JSON Array.  Then, you would add your class instance to an array of objects.

When you want to add them to SQLITE db, you might want to iterate through your class object array and send each instance up to a method to insert the data into the SQLITE database.  Here is an example of inserting data from an object into a SQLITE database:

```
    //---insert a new Location into the database---
public long insertLocation(LocationAddress location) 
{

    if (myDataBase == null) {
        openDataBase();
    }

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("name", location.getName());
    initialValues.put("address", location.getAddress());
    initialValues.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
    initialValues.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());
    initialValues.put("type", location.getType());
    initialValues.put("sort_order", location.getSortOrder());


    return myDataBase.insert("locations", null, initialValues);

}
```

There is a lot of other stuff related to using a SQLITE database, such as copying it from Assets on the first use, opening the database.  You should Google DataBaseHelper.java for examples of a utility file that has a lot of these methods ready for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Create POJO class from `json` and store it in `SQLite`

```
class ApiResponse {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    //getter-setter

}
```

Using `Gson`, parse the `jsonArray` to `List<ApiResponse>`

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ApiResponse>>() {}.getType();
List<ApiResponse> apiResponses = new Gson().fromJson(yourJson, listType);
```

Now `loop` through the list and store it into database

```
for(ApiResponse response: apiResponses) {
    //insert response into database
}
```

Comment: @ManiKandan, You reverse the accepted answer. what is the problem in my solution? Can you please clear so that I can correct myself? Thanks